# Nginx: use $http_host in location

Tags: nginx, alias

I got many server aliases in nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com site1.example.com site2.example.com site3.example.com
    ...
```

How i can control specific folder for alias in location of robots.txt file, for example i mean:

```
location ^~ $http_host/robots.txt {
    alias /home/web/public_html/static/$http_host/robots.txt;
}
```

Construction above not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$host` [nginx variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables):

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /home/web/public_html/static/$host/robots.txt;
}
```

Or:

```
location /robots.txt {
    root /home/web/public_html/static/$host;
}
```

By default `$host` stands for: *in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name matching a request.*

Comment: Thank you. That`s exactly what i need! Work very well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's possible. If it is someone will provide another answer.

Another approach is to create a server block for each site with any custom locations, then include any common directives in a common cile. Something like this

**example1.conf**

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name site1.example.com;

  include common1.conf;

  location ^~ robots.txt {
    alias /home/web/public_html/static/example1/robots.txt;
  }
}
```

**example2.conf**

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name site2.example.com;

  include common1.conf;

  location /abcd {
    //whatever
  }

  location ^~ robots.txt {
    alias /home/web/public_html/static/example2/robots.txt;
  }
}
```

**common1.conf**

```
location /common/location {
  //whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your `location` statement. It only matches the normalized URI sent from the user, that is, the part after domain name and possibly port in the URL and before query arguments.

Furthermore, you don't specify the actual filename in an `alias` directive, just the path where to find the file.

Therefore you need to use:

```
location /robots.txt {
    alias /home/web/public_html/static/example1;
}
```

in your configuration.